.NET Core 8 force sessione timeout
I create MVC application with .NET Core 8. This application, in production, runs on IIS. I need to force the session timeout to more than 20 minutes.
I tried in this way:
builder.Services.AddSession(options => { 
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
});

It works correctly outside of IIS, but in IIS it seems that this information are ignored.
To solve this I usually go in IIS Application Pools, Advanced settings and, in Process Model, I change Idle Time-out setting.
In this case I don't have access to IIS. It's possible to force this value from code?

asp.net core codes can't control IIS configurations. IIS application pool has it's own configuration for Idle Time-out which is used for keep the application alive. If we are not able to modify IIS configuration, we might create a keep alive background service, for example, sending a http request per 10 minutes.

@TinyWang the problem is when I close the browser. In this case I would have nothing that could ping the server.

Thanks for your confirmation, the keep-alive service might not send by the browser client, but can be an external service like Azure function, it's aim is to make the application pool not idle, you already set the session expire time to be one day, we just need to make sure the application pool isn't idle. Pls correct me if I misunderstood your concerns.

@TinyWang my application is hostend on somee with a free account. Unfortunately I can't manage application pool. Anyway, how can an external application keep alive my user session? They should be two completely separate things? Furthermore, the session never expires if I carry out any operation within the default 20 minutes.

the session is stored in the server, and if we set the session to be expired after 24h, the session should be existed in the server if the server is always alive, am I right? The issue we are facing is that, if we are able to set the application pool idle time to be 24h, then the session should work well. However we're not able to manage application pool, so that we need to have a workaround to make the application pool not idle. If the application pool is always alive, then our session would keep working. So I think we can have an external service to connect to our app maybe once per 20mins.

I mean, if we don't need to think about the application pool, my client has a session stored in the app and it will work for 24h. Then no matter I close my browser or keep it open, when I came back to my computer within 24h, I should get my session back right? But now we found that IIS application pool with be idle after 20mins by default. My browser can make the application pool not idle, and other clients also can make the application pool not idle. We can't make sure that there's always at least one client connect to the server, so that we need an external service to connect to the server..

This is just my idea. I never test it, and sorry in advance if my words confused you..

@TinyWang I think this isn't a valid solution. I did another try. I tried to set IdleTimeout to one minute but nothing change. My session and another person session are separate, so, a keep alive app, shouldn't change anything. Maybe I'll try it anyway.

set IdleTimeout to one minute but nothing change -> do you mean that you've had a test within an IIS which you are able to manage but changing the idle time didn't work for you? If so, you should change to a longer time-out limitation so that you could test whether the session stay alive for a longer time.

The default configuration for application pool is idletimeout for 20mins and the idle action is terminate. We all know that session is stored in the server side, if the application pool is terminated, then all the session are destoryed, that's why even we set the session timeout to be 24h but it doesn't work.
